# how can i pass data into array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

here i have data like this,

```
var dataArray = '[{"name":"books","value":43},{"name":"DVDs","value":99},{"name":"Magazines","value":37},{"name":"eBooks","value":88},{"name":"Other awesome things","value":67}]';
```

i want to construct this `chart` using this data dynamically, means my `json` will be large in actual project which will come from `database`.

here is jsfiddle for my desired `chart` (dynamically for my case):http://jsfiddle.net/artefactory/m4on9L4p/

```js
//canvasJS example - doughnut chart showing collection breakdown.   

var dataArray = '[{"name":"books","value":43},{"name":"DVDs","value":99},{"name":"Magazines","value":37},{"name":"eBooks","value":88},{"name":"Other awesome things","value":67}]';

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
        text: "What's in our collection"
      },
      data: [
      {
       type: "doughnut",
        // how to substitute above array here
       dataPoints: [
       {  y: 53.37, indexLabel: "Books" },
       {  y: 35.0, indexLabel: "DVDs" },
       {  y: 7, indexLabel: "Magazines" },
       {  y: 2, indexLabel: "eBooks" },
       {  y: 5, indexLabel: "Other awesome things" }
       ]
     }
     ]
   });

    chart.render();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.4.1/canvas.min.js"></script>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">  </div>
```

i want to build this

```
dataPoints: [
           {  y: 53.37, indexLabel: "Books" },
           {  y: 35.0, indexLabel: "DVDs" },
           {  y: 7, indexLabel: "Magazines" },
           {  y: 2, indexLabel: "eBooks" },
           {  y: 5, indexLabel: "Other awesome things" }
           ]
```

dynamically with my json.   how can i do it?

**Question:** instead of using `hardcoded` value i want to use `json` to build graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using `JSON.parse()` and `Array.prototype.map()` functions:

```
...
dataPoints:  JSON.parse(dataArray).map(function (o) {
    return {y: o.value, indexLabel: o.name};
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How are the values 53.37, 35.0 being derived? Is there a mathematical formula for their derivation?

If you just mapping "names" to indexLabel and "value" to x, then this piece of code should work.

```
var desiredObj = x.map(function(currentElement) {return {x: currentElement.value, indexLabel: currentElement.name}});
```

Comment: ha ha @Dinesh Verma, what you are asking man, what i want `dataPoints:[]` to be replaced by my `json` thats it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `map` function like this :

```
var myNewDataArray = $.map(dataArray,function(a,b){
    return {
        y : a.value,
        indexLabel : a.name
    }
});
```